# Can I change a column from NOT NULL to NULL without dropping it?

Tags: sql-server

Need to alter a table to allow nulls on a column -- but cant drop the column...can I do this?  Was trying something like:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY myColumn NULL;
```

But to no avail....

Answer (score 249, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn {DataType} NULL
```

where `{DataType}` is the current data type of that column (For example `int` or `varchar(10)`)

Answer (score 63):

Sure you can.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn int NULL
```

Just substitute int for whatever datatype your column is.

Comment: Actually your answer is true. but not accepted as best answer . phhhh . cause this ( ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn {DataType} NULL) doesn't work

Comment: I tried with `alter column` and it didn't work with the latest mysql server. I tried with `modify column` and it worked. Strange...

Comment: @UfukSURMEN, the {DataType} means that you should put whatever your datatype is instead of that. The answers are essentially the same, Mark just explained himself more (which should have earned him the accepted answer, but that's not my call).

Comment: @PrinceTyke Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is very based on database service

**SQL Server / MS Access:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype NULL;
```

**My SQL / Oracle (prior version 10G):**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype NULL;
```

**Oracle 10G and later:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype NULL;
```

**if you want to set a default value then:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype DEFAULT default_value;
```

Answer (score -1):

For MYSQL

```
ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY myColumn {DataType} NULL
```

Comment: don't know why this answer got downgraded, MODIFY column name works for mySql but not ALTER column name

Comment: @Venkat I think because the question is tagged sql-server.